# Possibility to change IC HCF4060BE to IC 74HC4060

Tags: integrated-circuit, cmos

I recently purchased a very old synthesizer that uses CI HCF4060BE and I want to know if it is the memso that CI 74HC4060.

To help here is the CI datasheet HCF4060BE: [LINK](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/philips/74HC4060.pdf)

Here the dataset of the CI 74HC4060: [LINK](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/stmicroelectronics/2055.pdf)

Here the base circuit of the synthesizer IC HCF4060BE:
[image]

One of the IC's burned out (it was a problem in the voltage regulator and one track that feeds the other CIs was broken saving the other ICs HCF4060BE).
I am very doubtful because this 74 ... works with 5 or 6v at the most, would that be a problem? why the filter circuit also works with 15v

Thank you all for helping me. I am a hobbyist and I understand the basics of circuits like this so I sent this question.

Comment: What is U1's power supply voltage?

Comment: 15v @EdgarBrown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It will not work, as a quick look at the data sheet would tell you. Specifically this table:

[image]

The CD40xx CMOS family has a wide range of operation voltages. The 74XXxxx families are 5V at most (except for specialized driver ICs).

But for that reason you can still find plenty of CD4000 & CD4000B series ICs in the market. Even in through-hole packages. The CD4060 is no exception. Both Digikey and Mouser has them by the truckload.

Comment: I understood, thanks for the answer, it's that I live in Brazil and it's very difficult to find it. no physical store has it or the internet here in Brazil.

Comment: I'm going to study importing via Mouser, because I think he has business with Brazil.

Comment: We are not supposed to promote any particular vendor, however mentioning several of them gets around that issue. There is also Newark and Allied. +1 for a quick, to the point answer.